# Click event listener doesn't trigger on select option

Tags: javascript, html

I want to understand why the click event is not triggered when an option from select is selected.
I created a select with few options and added click event on the document as follows

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => console.log(event.target));
```

```html
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

When I click some where in the page(document) it clearly logs the target element.

When I click on select it logs the target select element.

But when I click on one of the options from the select it doesn't seem to trigger click event.
Please help me understand this.

Comment: Clicking an options triggers it for me on Chrome

Comment: The click event is triggered when you click on the dropdown to open it, but not when you select an item.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't trigger when I select an option from the dropdown.

Comment: when an option from a select is selected, the event that fire is the "change" event , you can listen to it on the select element and get the selected value whenever the user click one of the options

Comment: Thank you, I am already aware of change event form select. But one of the libraries in my app is already listening to click events so I am just trying to understand why it is not working for options in select.